# How can I create a SQL query for a NEW row based on each column?

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a SQL table as follows:

```
name, email 1, email 2, email 3
John, john@example.com, info@example.com, hello@example.com
Mickey, mickey@disney.com, info@disney.com
```

I want to create a query to create a row for each email.

So the output would look like:

```
John, john@example.com
John, info@example.com
John, hello@example.com
Mickey, mickey@disney.com
Mickey, info@disney.com
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Tag yo r question with the database you are using.

Comment: One universal method is to use N joins or a union to fix the normalization. Then filter on null values. This is the "opposite" of group-by operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A database independent solution uses `union all`:

```
select name, email1 as email
from table1
where email1 is not null
union all
select name, email2 as email
from table1
where email2 is not null
union all
select name, email3 as email
from table1
where email3 is not null;
```

This requires scanning the table three times, so it is not the most efficient solution.  However, it is fine for small or medium sized tables.  The best solution depends on the particular database you are using -- if performance is an issue.

Comment: Can move the filter outside the union to reduce / move around SQL layout.

Comment: @user2864740 . . . You would need to use a CTE or subquery.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks! So basically, would it be correct to say that "union all" basically makes a virtual row base on parameters?

Comment: @SnowboardBruin . . . `union all` combines the results of two or more subqueries into a single result set, assuming they have the same number of columns and the types are compatible for each corresponding column.